# Assigning specific data from another webpage to variables or an array

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to take data from one webpage (that I don't own) and then manipulate that data. To do this I need to assign it to an array or write it to a MySQL DB or something. 
I want columns 2, 4 and 6 to be saved so I can use them. Below is my code so far, I'm completely lost on how to manipulate the data though. I think it's something to do with explode but I didn't manage to get that working:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML( $content );
//get all td
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
//display all text
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>"; 

//below doesn't work
$cells = explode(" ", $dom->getElementsByTagName('td'));
echo $cells;    

?>
```

Comment: What does var_dump($cells) give you?

Comment: @HydraIO The error for my whole explode is "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given". Adding var_dump after it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dom->getElementsByTagName('td');` would return a `DOMNodeList` datatype, not an `array`, so, doing an `explode` on this won't work, i guess.

Btw, what are you trying to do by exploding, when you are already looping through the `td`'s using `for`? Seems like similar stuff.

**Code**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML( $content );
//get all td
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

// save the 2nd, 4th and 6th column values
$columnsToSave = array( 2, 4, 6 );
$outputArray = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++ ) {
  $key = $i + 1;
  if( in_array( $key, $columnsToSave ) ) {
     $outputArray[ $key ] = $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
  }
}

print_r( $outputArray );
?>
```

Comment: I was trying a different way to see if that method was easier to get the end result. It proved to be more difficult than I expected to set up, but I left it in just in case it's relevant or helps someone help.

Comment: ok, the loop will work, explode won't. What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is a set of variables (or an array) I can use to save data from the 2nd, 4th and 6th columns in the table (so in my case, the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 10th, etc lines) - and then I'll be using that data in some simple math, so it needs to be accessible and not just printed to the page.

Comment: See my code if it works for you. Just took your code and added a few lines to it.

Comment: It gives me this 165 times: Notice: Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key'

Comment: sorry, i had written `key` instead of `$key`. corrected it, check now.